# How to create a parent / children relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this model in laravel 6.0.4:

```
class CategoryModel extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryModel::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryModel::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

And the controller

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        CategoryModel::with('children')->get(); // this is working
        CategoryModel::with('parent')->get(); // this is not working
    }
}
```

Here is the schema

```
Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');

    $table->index(['parent_id']);
    $table
        ->foreign('parent_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('category')
        ->onDelete('set null')
        ->onUpdate('set null');
});
```

I can get the children but for parent, it returns an empty array for all the records.

Comment: it seems your logic confuse , how can you get `parent and childrens` same `FK` name `parent_id`

Comment: @Hamelraj I've added the schema

Comment: as per you schema  `return $this->belongsTo(CategoryModel::class, 'parent_id');`
cause same `parent_id` has many times. 
but you get parent model from `children` relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was selecting the columns like this

```
CategoryModel::select('id', 'name')->with('parent')->get();
```

I did not know that I also should select the parent_id.
Now It's working fine with this

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryModel::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryModel::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryModel::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: It's returning children again

Comment: @RezaT1994 try to use hasOne instead of belongsTo. I have updated the answer.

Comment: any global scopes?

Comment: No global scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can use below  code to make relationship with self class:

```
public function parent()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryModel','parent_id')->where('parent_id',0)->with('parent') ;
}

 public function children()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryModel','parent_id')->with('children');
}
```

Comment: Here is the log from query. ```1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `category` where `category`.`parent_id` = ? and `parent_id` = ?"
    "bindings" => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 0
    ]
    "time" => 0.81
  ]``` and still not working